# How to open new JFrame using mouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, mouselistener

I'm trying to add a listener to my program that when a panel is clicked it will open a new JFrame.  For instance jpanel4 is the panel labled messages.  When I click on jpanel4 I would like it to open the SendMessages JFrame which is the SendMessages class.

Any insight on what direction I need to go?  Is this method even viable?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class UserProfile  extends javax.swing.JFrame implements MouseListener {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public UserProfile() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {



    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      //message panel
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel7 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel4.addMouseListener(this);      

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jLabel1.setText("Bio");

    jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea2.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);


      // Read the image file into an ImageIcon object.
       ImageIcon penguinsImage = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample     Pictures/penguins.jpg");
        //penguinsImage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60) );


     // Display the image in the label.
     jLabel8.setIcon(penguinsImage);
                    jLabel8.revalidate();
     // Remove the text from the label.
     jLabel8.setText(null);

     // jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
      javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addComponent(jLabel8)

        );  
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
             .addComponent(jLabel8)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel2.setText("Home");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jLabel3.setText("Messages");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
    jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
    jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jLabel4.setText("Events");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
    jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
    jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addContainerGap(48, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jLabel5.setText("Groups");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
    jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
    jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jLabel6.setText("Subscriptions");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel7Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel7);
    jPanel7.setLayout(jPanel7Layout);
    jPanel7Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel7Layout.setVerticalGroup(

            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup
            (jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(43, 43, 43))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jPanel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}
 // panel 4 listener
       private abstract class jPanel4Listener implements MouseListener
 {
    public static void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
     // opens the send message frame.
     SendMessage.setVisible(true); 


    }
 }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new UserProfile().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel7;
 private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel8;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is what I ended up using.

```
       private class menuBarListener  implements MouseListener
  {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    String c = e.getComponent().getName();


    if (c.equals("MessagePanel"))
    {
     // opens the send message frame. //dispose(); closes the current frame
       SendMessage s = new SendMessage();
          dispose ();
     s.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: An application should only have a single JFrame. You should use a JDialog for a secondary window.

Comment: To expand on @camickr comment.. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [How to mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), but basically

```
jpanel4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { 
        //...
    }
});
```